# Jasmine test for React causes Webpack build to fail

Tags: testing, jasmine, reactjs, webpack

I am building a simple site to show stories with React. I have made the first page that shows all the stories, so I wanted to set up my first test. I am new to testing React, but I have done a bit with Jasmine, so I used Jasmine for my tests. I think that I've set up my test file right, but when I try to build with Webpack, I get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: /home/michael/repository/short-stories/test/karma_tests/story_test.js Line 14: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

My test file looks like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var Story = require('../../app/js/components/story.jsx');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

  describe('Story component', function () {

    afterEach(function () {
      if (component && TestUtils.isCompositeComponent(component) && component.isMounted()) {
        React.unmountComponentAtNode(component.getDOMNode().parent);
      }
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
      component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Story />);
      component.props.data.storyTitle = 'front end test title';
      component.props.data.author = 'front end author';
      component.props.data.storyText = 'front end story text';
    });

    it('should display a story', function () {
      expect(component.props.data.storyTitle).toBeDefined();
      expect(component.props.data.storyTitle).toBe('front end test title');
    });

  });
```

My webpack task in my Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
 webpack: {
      client: {
        entry: __dirname + '/app/js/client.jsx',
        output: {
          path: 'build/',
          file: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
          loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader:'jsx-loader'
          }]
        }
      },
      test: {
        entry: __dirname + '/test/client/test.js',
        output: {
          path: 'test/client/',
          file: 'bundle.js'
        }
      },
      karma_test: {
        entry: __dirname + '/test/karma_tests/test_entry.js',
        output: {
          path: 'test/karma_tests/',
          file: 'bundle.js'
        }
      }
    },
```

Let me know if more info would help find a solution. You can view the full project on my github repo: https://github.com/mrbgit/short-stories/tree/react-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack is not able to parse your code. You are using JSX syntax in a JS file. renderIntoDocument takes a React element instance

```
component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(React.createElement('story'));
```

Comment: Thanks M_rivermount, that along with adding the jsx-loader to the karma tests made the build work. But now when I run the test I get the error: "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Comment: I updated my answer. It is out of scope for this question but require is not defined because you need to use webpack as a preprocessor in Karma OR you need to include the already processed file which in your case is karma_tests/bundle.js

Comment: Thanks M_rivermount, the build runs now. Next I need to work on getting the tests to run correctly!